# Как создать такой дизайн (волны)

Tags: css

Как мне сделать такие волны. Там вся сложность в перекрытии цветов. не могу понять, они как-то непонятно накладываются друг на друга.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно с помощью `svg`. вот пример https://codepen.io/gbnikolov/pen/rLzxoX,
вашу картинку в илюстраторе можете сделать в svg формате и поставить здесь.

Answer (score 0):

Рисуешь в иллюстраторе (или в чем нибудь другом). Ставишь фоном блока. Все.